# ggplot2 geom_area graph; not sure what I am missing here

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing

**Here is my coding:**

```
library(ggplot2)
Graph2 <- read.csv("~/ggplot2 project/Graph2.csv", sep="")
ggplot(Graph2, aes(x=Year, y=Total, fill=Season)) + geom_area()
```

**This is my result:**

[image]

**But I am trying to get it to look more like:**

[image]

Any idea where I went wrong here?

Comment: Could you include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Regrets but I'm really new to R and ggplot2, could you be expand on what you are looking for as an example? Thanks

Comment: See the answers of the [**Q & A**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) I linked to above. The first one already gives you very good guidance on how to construct a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Posting `dput(Graph2)` would pretty much get us there.